# Suppress warnings for files imported from the "Library Search Paths"

Tags: ios, objective-c, suppress-warnings

I have a project where I import third party files with the *Library Search Paths*:

[image: Library Search Paths in Build Settings]

There are a lot of warning from those files. How can I remove those ?

I know I can use `-w` in the *Compile Sources* in the *Build Phases*:

[image: Compile Sources in the Build Phases]

But is there another way so I don't have to import my files into the *Compile Sources* ?

### Edit:

Here are some warnings that I have :

[image: Compile Warnings]

(They come from a run script that makes all FIXME and TODO's as warnings)

**After checking my project,** I see that I'm importing a static library named libSVGKit-iOS.a and I think it maybe this causing the warnings.
Is there a way to remove them ?

### Resolution:

I resolve my problem by changing the run script that was making all `TODO`'s and `FIXME`'s by ignoring files in my third party folder because their `TODO`'s and `FIXME`'s are not related to me.

For information, my old script was :

```
KEYWORDS="TODO:|FIXME:|XXX:|\?\?\?:|\!\!\!:"
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" \) -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($KEYWORDS)/ warning: \$1/"
```

My new script is :

```
KEYWORDS="TODO:|FIXME:|XXX:|\?\?\?:|\!\!\!:"
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" \) -and \(\! -name "*3rd Party*" \) -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($KEYWORDS)/ warning: \$1/"
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense as *Library Search Paths* affects the linker, not the compiler.

Comment: @trojanfoe When I compile my project I have warnings on those files.

Comment: That's got nothing to do with the library search path. Post the actual warning messages.

Comment: @trojanfoe I edited my question with the warnings I have.

Comment: Do you have your library source code apart .a file?

Comment: I only have the .a file and the header (.h) files.